# How to search with SearchCriteria like as "search_term" how as frontend input search

Tags: magento2

I need an equivalent search result between SearchCriteria and the search term on the frontend, in other words, when I search the store via the frontend, it brings a number of results, but already via the API, it brings another one, I need something that is equivalent, my searchCriteria filters must be wrong.

```
/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25malbec%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][4][filters][0][field]=is_salable&searchCriteria[filter_groups][4][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][4][filters][0][value]=1
```